# EF Core Error: The provider does not support 'DateOnly'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, integration-testing, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 web API that starts up fine, and all migrations run successfully. Now, I'm writing integration tests for the API. For integration testing, a separate database should be created, not in-memory.

ApiWebApplicationFactory:

```
using Api;
using Infrastructure.Database;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace TestsApi.Common
{
    public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
        public AccountinglocusContext DbContext { get; private set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
            {
                Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("integrationsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                config.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
            });

            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => 
            {              
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d =>
                            d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<AccountinglocusContext>));

                services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

                var dbConnectionDescriptor = services
                    .SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbConnection));

                services.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor);

                ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrTest");
                services.AddDbContext<AccountinglocusContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));

                var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
                DbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AccountinglocusContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

integrationsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionStrTest": "Data Source=(Localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=Integration;Integrated Security=True"
  }
}
```

When running tests, I encounter the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The 'DateOnly' property 'VatPeriod.FromDate' could not be mapped to the database type 'date' because the database provider does not support mapping 'DateOnly' properties to 'date' columns. Consider mapping to a different database type or converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

This error occurs only when running tests; the API starts without any issues. It seems to be related to the `DateOnly` type, but why does it happen only during test execution?

I don't understand how to solve this issue and why it only occurs in tests.

If more information is needed, please let me know.

I managed to fix the error above by adding a `DateOnly` type converter.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

namespace Infrastructure.Helpers
{
    public class DateOnlyConverter : ValueConverter<DateOnly, DateTime>
    {
        public DateOnlyConverter() : base(
            d => d.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
            d => DateOnly.FromDateTime(d))
        { }
    }   
}
```

```
using Infrastructure.Helpers;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using System.Data;

namespace Infrastructure.Database
{
    public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        private IDbContextTransaction? _currentTransaction;

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
                .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter>();
        }
    }
}
```

But now a new error has appeared:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The current provider doesn't have a store type mapping for properties of type 'DateOnly'."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Which DataProvider is used for production and which for integration testing?

Comment: Also which ADO.NET driver? DateOnly support was added in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1. Instead of writing your own converters though you can use ErikEJ's [NuGet package](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2023/09/03/efcore-dateonly-timeonly.html). This adds full query support, not just type conversion

Comment: and for tests and for API I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  @Svyatoslav Danyliv

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos
Thank you very much. I installed the package you suggested, also learned why ADO.NET is needed, and after that, everything started working. Thank you very much @Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

I use the same converter, but in the builder I also added `.HaveColumnType("date");`, that indicate the data type to use in the database.
This work for SQL Server DBMS, if you are using something else use the appropriate data type.

```cs
builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
    .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter>()
    .HaveColumnType("date");
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the [NuGet package ErikEJ](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2023/09/03/efcore-dateonly-timeonly.html), everything started working correctly.

thanks for the help [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)